# tikz - generate video test pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf

I got a video test pattern looks like below. it's a picture taken by camera from other one. It's burry and I would like to generate a digital one myself. Is tikz good for such picture or any other software can be used?

[image]

My draft version after reading @Schrödinger's cat's reply:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,positioning,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    %\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \def\rsize{4}
    \def\d{0.5}
    \tikzset{
        background rectangle/.style={
            fill={rgb,255:red,150; green,150; blue,150}
        },show background rectangle,
        % box1 and box2
        box1/.style={draw,line width=2pt,minimum width={\rsize*1.8cm},minimum height={\rsize*1.8cm},anchor=center},
        mat/.style={matrix,inner sep=0},
        % colmat
        pics/colmat/.style={code={
                \tikzset{colmat/.cd,#1}  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colmat/##1}}%
                \edef\m{\pv{m}}%
                \edef\w{1.8}%
                \foreach \row [count=\j] in \m  {
                    \foreach \r/\g/\b [count=\i] in \row {
                        \fill[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}] (\i*\w-\w,\j*\w-\w) rectangle ++(\w,\w);
                    }%foreach
                }%foreach
        }},colmat/.cd,m/.initial={{255/0/0}},/tikz/.cd,
        % rad 
    pics/rad/.style={code={
        \tikzset{rad/.cd,#1}%
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rad/##1}}%
        \fill[white] (0,0) -- (0:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=\pv{r}]
        -- (-90:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-180,radius=\pv{r}] -- cycle;
        \fill[black] (0,0) -- (90:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=90,end angle=180,radius=\pv{r}]
        -- (0:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=0,end angle=-90,radius=\pv{r}] -- cycle;
}},rad/.cd,r/.initial=1,/tikz/.cd,
% disk
pics/disk/.style={code={
        \tikzset{disk/.cd,#1}%
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/disk/##1}}%
        \colorlet{diskfill}{\pv{fill}}%
        \draw[diskfill] circle[radius=\pv{r}];
        \fill[\pv{bg}] (0,0) foreach \XX in {1,2,...,120}
        { -- (0.5+\XX*3:0.9*\pv{r}) 
            arc[start angle=0.5+\XX*3,end angle=2.5+\XX*3,radius=0.9*\pv{r}]
            -- (0,0) };
        \path (0,0) pic{rad};
        \draw[\pv{bg},line width=5pt,pic actions]  circle[radius=0.95*\pv{r}];
}},disk/.cd,bg/.initial=white,fill/.initial=gray!40,r/.initial=2,/tikz/.cd,
%mycross
pics/mycross/.style={code={
        \draw[rotate = 0,line width=5pt] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw[rotate = 0,line width=5pt] (0,-1) -- (0, 1);
}},
% random circles
pics/random circles/.style={code={
        \tikzset{random circles/.cd,#1}%
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circles/##1}}%
        \colorlet{rfill}{\pv{fill}}%
        \fill[rfill] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
        \clip  (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
        \foreach \XX in {1,...,\pv{n}}
        {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{(rnd<\pv{f} ? 0 :1)}
            \ifnum\itest=0
            \fill[white,opacity=\pv{opacity}] (-0.5+rnd,-0.5+rnd) 
            circle[radius=rnd*rnd*rnd*\pv{r}];
            \else
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myR}{rnd*256-0.0001}%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myG}{rnd*256-0.0001}%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myB}{rnd*256-0.0001}%
            \definecolor{myrnd}{RGB}{\myR,\myG,\myB}%
            \fill[myrnd!50,opacity=\pv{opacity}] (-0.5+rnd,-0.5+rnd) 
            circle[radius=rnd*rnd*rnd*\pv{r}];
            \fi}
}},random circles/.cd,r/.initial=0.2,n/.initial=120,fill/.initial=gray!40,
opacity/.initial=0.2,f/.initial=0.3,
};
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\def\r{35}
% corner disks with rads
\foreach \a [count=\i] in {30,150,-150,-30} {
    \path[disk/r=\rsize] (O) ++ (\a:\r) pic{disk} coordinate (D\i);
    \foreach \x [count=\j] in {45,135,...,360} {
        \path (D\i) ++ (\x:{\rsize*1.3}) pic{rad={r=0.5}} coordinate(E-\i-\j);
    }
}
% rads around side
\foreach \fx\fy/\tx/\ty in {1/1/2/2,2/2/3/3,3/3/4/4,4/4/1/1} {
    \path (E-\fx-\fy) -- (E-\tx-\ty) 
    \foreach \j in {0,0.25,0.5,0.75} {
        pic[pos=\j] {rad}
    };
}

% cross
\foreach \i in {45,135,...,360} {
    \path (0,0) ++(\i:{\rsize*4cm}) pic{mycross};
}

% disk side
\def\r{25}
\foreach \a in {15,-165} {
    \path[disk/r=\rsize] (0,0) ++ (\a:\r) node[box1] {} pic{disk};
}
\foreach \a in {165,-15} {
    \path[disk/r=\rsize,disk/bg=gray!50] (0,0) ++ (\a:\r) node[box1] {} pic{disk};
}

% center
\def\r{2}
\def\al{2*\rsize}
\def\bl{\rsize/2}
\draw[fill=black] (-\r,-\r) rectangle (\r,\r);
\foreach \t in {0,0.2,...,2} {
    \draw[white,line width=\t] (0,0) circle (\t);
}
% 4 wheels
\def\xlst{
    -45/238/229/225/35/20/17,
    45/108/94/94/194/187/185,
    135/195/188/186/111/100/97,
    -135/40/28/27/239/230/226%
}
\foreach \a/\rx/\gx/\bx/\ry/\gy/\by[count=\i] in \xlst {
    \draw[fill={rgb,255:red,\rx; green,\gx; blue,\bx}] (\a:{\r*sqrt(2)})  -- ([turn]45:\al) -- ([turn]90:\bl)  coordinate (L\i)  -- cycle;
    \draw[fill={rgb,255:red,\ry; green,\gy; blue,\by}] (\a:{\r*sqrt(2)})  -- ([turn]135:\bl) -- ([turn]-90:\al)  -- cycle;
}
% center grass
\def\offset{{(\rsize+\r)*sqrt(2)}}
\path[rad/r=0.5] (135:\offset) pic[scale={\rsize*2}]{random circles}
++ (45:{\rsize*sqrt(2)}) pic{rad} ++ (-{2*\rsize},0)  pic{rad}
++ (0,-{2*\rsize})  pic{rad}  ++ ({2*\rsize},0)  pic{rad}
(-45:\offset) pic[scale={\rsize*2}]{random circles}
++ (45:{\rsize*sqrt(2)}) pic{rad} ++ (-{2*\rsize},0)  pic{rad}
++ (0,-{2*\rsize})  pic{rad}  ++ ({2*\rsize},0)  pic{rad};
% center disks
\path[disk/r=\rsize] (0,0) ++ (45:\offset) pic{disk};
\path[disk/r=\rsize,disk/bg=gray!50] (0,0) ++ (-135:\offset) pic{disk};
% P start
      \def\clst{
        {245/240/235},
        {233/226/224},
        {223/216/214},
        {209/202/200},
        {190/183/181}%
    }
  \node[right=\d of L1,mat] (P1) {\pic{colmat={m=\clst}};\\};
\def\clst{
    {255/251/244,255/255/255,255/255/255,255/255/254,255/246/242}%
}
\node[above=\d of L2,mat] (P2) {\pic{colmat={m=\clst}};\\};
      \def\clst{
        {252/243/238},
        {242/234/228},
        {231/222/218},
        {216/209/207},
        {200/193/191}%
    }
  \node[left=\d of L3,mat] (P3) {\pic{colmat={m=\clst}};\\};
      \def\clst{
    {177/171/169,123/113/114,27/17/12,40/32/30,152/145/145}%
}
\node[below=\d of L4,matrix] (P4) {\pic{colmat={m=\clst}};\\};
% P end

%M start
\def\clst{
    {255/230/208,135/19/19,225/13/86},
    {237/255/240,253/42/28,118/17/42},
    {250/239/240,238/151/162,235/14/44},
    {232/247/247,255/161/141,255/53/27},
    {218/211/209,255/163/31,255/211/15},
    {118/106/103,237/221/11,255/225/7},
    {31/18/12,200/176/42,224/223/10},
    {189/194/44,211/231/13,78/24/12}%
}
\node[right=\d of P1,mat] (M1) {\pic{colmat={m=\clst}};\\};
\def\clst{
    {118/14/5,221/169/143,110/142/174,69/102/32,164/157/198,157/225/210},
    {254/164/24,45/90/186,217/20/39,120/20/130,198/212/17,245/190/18},
    {48/43/169,106/186/61,218/17/22,250/211/9,226/80/181,0/163/194},
    {255/255/255,235/225/224,201/191/192,140/133/133,63/51/48,23/11/10}%
}
\node[above=\d of P2,mat] (M2) {\pic{colmat={m=\clst}};\\};
\def\clst{
    {194/22/135,82/27/113,239/240/237},
    {232/172/222,158/116/203,255/232/231},
    {168/43/169,18/55/119,228/255/250},
    {20/176/221,147/198/225,255/231/220},
    {112/207/221,17/51/75,250/250/206},
    {12/49/45,174/201/231,243/161/95},
    {120/217/215,0/195/195,234/179/154},
    {32/19/13,129/211/163,0/191/142}%
}
\node[left=\d of P3,mat] (M3) {\pic{colmat={m=\clst}};\\};
\def\clst{
    {27/14/11,40/28/27,101/90/84,184/178/178,228/221/219,255/255/255},
    {255/207/175,218/174/127,167/101/34,226/181/158,186/98/28,239/172/135},
    {255/198/167,224/182/158,224/183/154,227/179/152,136/37/9,239/179/145},
    {11/41/28,101/211/186,150/196/49,97/196/63,83/210/57,216/161/39}%
%
}
\node[below=\d of P4,mat] (M4) {\pic{colmat={m=\clst}};\\};
% M end
%
\draw[red] (current bounding box.north east) -- (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
% keep ratio
\def\ratio{16/9}
\path let \p1=(current bounding box.center),
\p2=(current bounding box.east),
\p3=(current bounding box.north),
\p4=(current bounding box.west),
\p5=(current bounding box.south),
\n1={\y3-\y1},
\n2={\n1*\ratio},
\n3={\y5 - \y1},
\n4={\n3*\ratio}
in 
[use as bounding box] (\n4,\y5) rectangle (\n2,\y3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is certainly possible to draw something like this with Ti*k*Z. In order to avoid this becoming overly tedious, you can define `pic`s. Obviously I did not attempt to fully recreate the picture but give some examples.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/random array/.style={code={
      \tikzset{random array/.cd,#1}%
      \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random array/##1}}%
      \edef\mysize{\pv{size}}%
      \def\pft##1x##2;{\edef\mynx{##1}\edef\myny{##2}}%
      \expandafter\pft\mysize;%
      \foreach \XX in {1,...,\mynx}
      {\foreach \YY in {1,...,\myny}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myR}{rnd*256-0.0001}%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myG}{rnd*256-0.0001}%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myB}{rnd*256-0.0001}%
       \definecolor{myrnd}{RGB}{\myR,\myG,\myB}%
       \fill[myrnd] (-\mynx/2+\XX-1,-\myny/2+\YY-1) rectangle ++ (1,1);
     }}
    %
    }},random array/.cd,size/.initial=4x4,/tikz/.cd,
    pics/rad/.style={code={
      \tikzset{rad/.cd,#1}%
      \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rad/##1}}%
      \fill[white] (0,0) -- (0:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=\pv{r}]
      -- (-90:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-180,radius=\pv{r}] -- cycle;
      \fill[black] (0,0) -- (90:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=90,end angle=180,radius=\pv{r}]
      -- (0:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=0,end angle=-90,radius=\pv{r}] -- cycle;
    }},rad/.cd,r/.initial=0.2,/tikz/.cd,
    pics/disk/.style={code={
      \tikzset{disk/.cd,#1}%
      \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/disk/##1}}%
      \colorlet{diskfill}{\pv{fill}}%
      \draw[diskfill] circle[radius=\pv{r}];
      \fill[white] (0,0) foreach \XX in {1,...,120}
       { -- (0.5+\XX*3:0.9*\pv{r}) 
        arc[start angle=0.5+\XX*3,end angle=2.5+\XX*3,radius=0.9*\pv{r}]
        -- (0,0) };
      \draw[white,pic actions]  circle[radius=0.95*\pv{r}];
    }},disk/.cd,fill/.initial=gray!40,r/.initial=1,/tikz/.cd,
    ]
    \fill[gray!30] (-10,-8) rectangle (10,8);
    \path (0,0) pic[scale=0.5]{random array={size={3x6}}}
     (3,1) pic{rad}
     (-4,-2) pic{disk} ++ (1,1) pic{rad} ++ (-2,0) pic{rad} ++ (0,-2) pic {rad}
     ++ (2,0) pic{rad};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Zoom into circle shape `disk`.

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: The missing pic in your update added.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{graphicx} %<- gets loaded by tikz
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,positioning,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=south west,background rectangle/.style={fill={rgb,255:red,150; green,150; blue,150}},
    show background rectangle]
    \tikzset{
        box1/.style={draw,line width=2pt,minimum width=9cm,minimum height=9cm,anchor=center},
    pics/rad/.style={code={
        \tikzset{rad/.cd,#1}%
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rad/##1}}%
        \fill[white] (0,0) -- (0:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=\pv{r}]
        -- (-90:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-180,radius=\pv{r}] -- cycle;
        \fill[black] (0,0) -- (90:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=90,end angle=180,radius=\pv{r}]
        -- (0:\pv{r}) arc[start angle=0,end angle=-90,radius=\pv{r}] -- cycle;
}},rad/.cd,r/.initial=1,/tikz/.cd,
pics/disk/.style={code={
        \tikzset{disk/.cd,#1}%
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/disk/##1}}%
        \colorlet{diskfill}{\pv{fill}}%
        \draw[diskfill] circle[radius=\pv{r}];
        \fill[white] (0,0) foreach \XX in {1,...,120}
        { -- (0.5+\XX*3:0.9*\pv{r}) 
            arc[start angle=0.5+\XX*3,end angle=2.5+\XX*3,radius=0.9*\pv{r}]
            -- (0,0) };
        \path (0,0) pic{rad};
        \draw[white,line width=5pt,pic actions]  circle[radius=0.95*\pv{r}];
}},disk/.cd,fill/.initial=gray!40,r/.initial=5,/tikz/.cd,
pics/random circles/.style={code={
        \tikzset{random circles/.cd,#1}%
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circles/##1}}%
        \colorlet{rfill}{\pv{fill}}%
        \fill[rfill] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
        \clip  (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
        \foreach \XX in {1,...,\pv{n}}
        {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{(rnd<\pv{f} ? 0 :1)}
        \ifnum\itest=0
         \fill[white,opacity=\pv{opacity}] (-0.5+rnd,-0.5+rnd) 
          circle[radius=rnd*rnd*rnd*\pv{r}];
        \else
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myR}{rnd*256-0.0001}%
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myG}{rnd*256-0.0001}%
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myB}{rnd*256-0.0001}%
         \definecolor{myrnd}{RGB}{\myR,\myG,\myB}%
         \fill[myrnd!50,opacity=\pv{opacity}] (-0.5+rnd,-0.5+rnd) 
          circle[radius=rnd*rnd*rnd*\pv{r}];
        \fi}
}},random circles/.cd,r/.initial=0.2,n/.initial=120,fill/.initial=gray!40,
opacity/.initial=0.2,f/.initial=0.3
};
   \path[rad/r=0.5] (135:12) pic[scale=10]{random circles}
    ++ (45:{5*sqrt(2)}) pic{rad} ++ (-10,0)  pic{rad}
    ++ (0,-10)  pic{rad}  ++ (10,0)  pic{rad}
    (-45:12) pic[scale=10]{random circles}
    ++ (45:{5*sqrt(2)}) pic{rad} ++ (-10,0)  pic{rad}
    ++ (0,-10)  pic{rad}  ++ (10,0)  pic{rad};
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\def\r{40}
\foreach \alpha [count=\i] in {30,150,-150,-30} {
    \path (0,0) ++ (\alpha:\r) pic{disk} coordinate (D\i);
    \foreach \x in {45,135,...,360} {
        \path (D\i) ++ (\x:7) pic{rad={r=0.5}};
    }
}

\path ([yshift=8cm]D1) -- ([yshift=8cm]D2) pic[pos=0.5]{rad}  pic[pos=0.5]{rad}  pic[pos=0.3]{rad}  pic[pos=0]{rad} pic[pos=1]{rad};
\path ([yshift=-8cm]D3) -- ([yshift=-8cm]D4) pic[pos=0.5]{rad}  pic[pos=0.3]{rad}  pic[pos=0.7]{rad}  pic[pos=0]{rad} pic[pos=1]{rad};
\path ([xshift=8cm]D1) -- ([xshift=8cm]D4) pic[pos=0.5]{rad}  pic[pos=0.3]{rad}  pic[pos=0.7]{rad};
\path ([xshift=-8cm]D2) -- ([xshift=-8cm]D3) pic[pos=0.5]{rad}  pic[pos=0.3]{rad}  pic[pos=0.7]{rad};

\def\x{30}
\def\y{7}
%\path (0,0) ++ (\x,\y) };
\path (0,0) ++ (\x,\y) node[box1] {} pic{disk};
\path (0,0) ++ (-\x,\y) node[box1] {}  pic{disk};
\path (0,0) ++ (-\x,-\y) node[box1] {}  pic{disk};
\path (0,0) ++ (\x,-\y) node[box1] {} pic{disk};

\path (0,0) ++ (45:12) pic{disk};
\path (0,0) ++ (-135:12) pic{disk};

\def\r{2}
\def\al{12}
\def\bl{3}
\draw[fill=black] (-\r,-\r) rectangle (\r,\r);
\foreach \t in {0,0.2,...,2} {
    \draw[white,line width=\t] (0,0) circle (\t);
}

\def\xlst{
    -45/238/229/225/35/20/17,
    45/108/94/94/194/187/185,
    135/195/188/186/111/100/97,
    -135/40/28/27/239/230/226%
}

\foreach \a/\rx/\gx/\bx/\ry/\gy/\by[count=\i] in \xlst {
    \draw[fill={rgb,255:red,\rx; green,\gx; blue,\bx}] (\a:{\r*sqrt(2)})  -- ([turn]45:\al) -- ([turn]90:\bl)  coordinate (L\i)  -- cycle;
    \draw[fill={rgb,255:red,\ry; green,\gy; blue,\by}] (\a:{\r*sqrt(2)})  -- ([turn]135:\bl) -- ([turn]-90:\al)  -- cycle;
}


      \matrix [left=4cm of L3 ,matrix of nodes,draw,
nodes in empty cells,anchor=east,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={draw,
    minimum height=2cm,
    minimum width=2cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    align=center},
] (M1)
{
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\      
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\      
};       
\def\clst{
    {194/22/135,82/27/113,239/240/237},
    {232/172/222,158/116/203,255/232/231},
    {168/43/169,18/55/119,228/255/250},
    {20/176/221,147/198/225,255/231/220},
    {112/207/221,17/51/75,250/250/206},
    {12/49/45,174/201/231,243/161/95},
    {120/217/215,0/195/195,234/179/154},
    {32/19/13,129/211/163,0/191/142}%
}
\foreach \row[count=\rn] in \clst {
    \foreach \r/\g/\b[count=\cn] in \row {
        \node[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}, fit=(M1-\rn-\cn) ]   {};
    }
}

% P start
      \matrix [right=1cm of L1,matrix of nodes,draw,
nodes in empty cells,anchor=west,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={draw,
    minimum height=2cm,
    minimum width=2cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    align=center},
] (M2)
{
     \\
     \\
     \\
     \\
     \\
};       
\def\clst{
    {245/240/235},
    {233/226/224},
    {223/216/214},
    {209/202/200},
    {190/183/181}%
}
\foreach \row[count=\rn] in \clst {
    \foreach \r/\g/\b[count=\cn] in \row {
        \node[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}, fit=(M2-\rn-\cn) ]   {};
    }
}

      \matrix [above=1cm of L2,matrix of nodes,draw,
nodes in empty cells,anchor=south,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={draw,
    minimum height=2cm,
    minimum width=2cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    align=center},
] (M2)
{
    & & & & \\
};       
\def\clst{
    {255/251/244,255/255/255,255/255/255,255/255/254,255/246/242}%
}
\foreach \row[count=\rn] in \clst {
    \foreach \r/\g/\b[count=\cn] in \row {
        \node[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}, fit=(M2-\rn-\cn) ]   {};
    }
}

      \matrix [left=1cm of L3,matrix of nodes,draw,
nodes in empty cells,anchor=east,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={draw,
    minimum height=2cm,
    minimum width=2cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    align=center},
] (M2)
{
    \\
    \\
    \\
    \\
    \\
};       
\def\clst{
    {252/243/238},
    {242/234/228},
    {231/222/218},
    {216/209/207},
    {200/193/191}%
}
\foreach \row[count=\rn] in \clst {
    \foreach \r/\g/\b[count=\cn] in \row {
        \node[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}, fit=(M2-\rn-\cn) ]   {};
    }
}
% P end

      \matrix [right=4cm of L1,matrix of nodes,draw,
nodes in empty cells,anchor=west,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={draw,
    minimum height=2cm,
    minimum width=2cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    align=center},
] (M2)
{
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\      
    &  &  \\
    &  &  \\      
};       
\def\clst{
    {255/230/208,135/19/19,225/13/86},
    {237/255/240,253/42/28,118/17/42},
    {250/239/240,238/151/162,235/14/44},
    {232/247/247,255/161/141,255/53/27},
    {218/211/209,255/163/31,255/211/15},
    {118/106/103,237/221/11,255/225/7},
    {31/18/12,200/176/42,224/223/10},
    {189/194/44,211/231/13,78/24/12}%
}
\foreach \row[count=\rn] in \clst {
    \foreach \r/\g/\b[count=\cn] in \row {
        \node[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}, fit=(M2-\rn-\cn) ]   {};
    }
}

          \matrix [above=4cm of L2,matrix of nodes,draw,
nodes in empty cells,anchor=south,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={draw,
    minimum height=2cm,
    minimum width=2cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    align=center},
] (M3)
{
    &  &  & & & \\
    &  &  & & & \\
    &  &  & & & \\
    &  &  & & & \\
};       
\def\clst{
    {118/14/5,221/169/143,110/142/174,69/102/32,164/157/198,157/225/210},
    {254/164/24,45/90/186,217/20/39,120/20/130,198/212/17,245/190/18},
    {48/43/169,106/186/61,218/17/22,250/211/9,226/80/181,0/163/194},
    {255/255/255,235/225/224,201/191/192,140/133/133,63/51/48,23/11/10}%
}
\foreach \row[count=\rn] in \clst {
    \foreach \r/\g/\b[count=\cn] in \row {
        \node[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}, fit=(M3-\rn-\cn) ]   {};
    }
}

          \matrix [below=4 of L4,matrix of nodes,draw,
nodes in empty cells,anchor=north,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={draw,
    minimum height=2cm,
    minimum width=2cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    align=center},
] (M4)
{
    &  &  & & & \\
    &  &  & & & \\
    &  &  & & & \\
    &  &  & & & \\
};       
\def\clst{
    {27/14/11,40/28/27,101/90/84,184/178/178,228/221/219,255/255/255},
    {255/207/175,218/174/127,167/101/34,226/181/158,186/98/28,239/172/135},
    {255/198/167,224/182/158,224/183/154,227/179/152,136/37/9,239/179/145},
    {11/41/28,101/211/186,150/196/49,97/196/63,83/210/57,216/161/39}%
%
}
\foreach \row[count=\rn] in \clst {
    \foreach \r/\g/\b[count=\cn] in \row {
        \node[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}, fit=(M4-\rn-\cn) ]   {};
    }
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  the difficult things is the disk, it looks like draw some lines from circle center to border, but the lines width is increasing from center to border. how can tikz do such drawings!

Comment: @lucky1928 Please see the update.

Comment: Great, would you please help comment on my draft version (updated). I still no idea about how to the center part and the soil/grass like blocks!

Comment: @lucky1928 I added a proposal.